# Backbone views not rendering in order

Tags: layout, backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs, router

In my app I have layouts and views for those layouts. Layouts only change on login/logout, but the other special case is on pageload I need to load the proper layout. However, in my `defaultAction` my layout does not actually render after it returns and so when the view tries to render, the `el` it is supposed to be contained in does not exist.

```
// Filename: router.js
var app_router;
define( [ 'views/layouts/beta', 'views/beta/requestInvite', 'views/beta/login', 'views/app/dashboard' ],
function(betaLayout, requestInviteView, loginView, dashboardView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend( {
        routes : {
            // Pages
            'login' : 'login',
            'dashboard' : 'dashboard',

            // Default
            '*actions' : 'defaultAction'
        },

        // Pages
        login : function() {
            loginView.render();
        },

        dashboard : function() {
            dashboardView.render();
        },

        // Default
        defaultAction : function(actions) {
            betaLayout.render();
            requestInviteView.render();
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {
        app_router = new AppRouter;

        $('a').live('click', function() {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            // only navigate to real links
            if(href == undefined)
                return;

            app_router.navigate(href, {trigger: true});

            return false;
        });

        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    };
    return {
        initialize : initialize
    };
});
```

How can I have my layout render completely before my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that because my layout didn't render before my view was initialized, the `el` was empty. What I did was convert all of my objects to return the **object** instead of the **instance**, and let them `render` once they were initialized. This way, when I declare a `new MyLayout` and then a `new MyView`, I can be guaranteed that `MyView`'s `el` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Define a callback for `betaLayout.render()` to take as an argument, that gets executed when the render is actually complete.

E.g., `betaLayout.render()` would look something like:

```
render: function(callback) {
    /* code to render your element,
       using the following line when all
       asynchronous calls are complete */
    if (callback) callback();
}
```

and your `defaultAction` would use it like so, passing the second `render()` as its callback.

```
betaLayout.render(requestInviteView.render);
```

Comment: I tried that at first, but it turned out that the layout had already rendered, except the view had been initialized **before**, so the `el` was empty.

Comment: Ah, so you're manipulating `betaLayout`'s `el` during `requestInviteView`'s `initialize`? Since it looks like you're returning an instance from the required files try the [order! plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/download.html#order) (if you're using RequireJS 1.0) to force the files to execute and be initialized in the right order.

Otherwise, if possible, shift the manipulation code into `requestInviteView`'s `render` so that you can explicitly control when it's executed.